# Postgres Triggers For Keeping Canonical Table Synchronized With Raw Tables

Tags: postgresql, database-design, triggers

For example, I have two raw tables

```
Table: vendor1_sales

id,  location,  date_string,            cents
1,  'CA',       '2020-01-01 00:00:00',  400
2,  'MA',       '2020-02-02 00:12:34',  99

Table: vendor2_sales

id,  state,  unix_timestamp,  dollars
1,  'CA',    1616285727,      0.98
2,  'NY',    1616284000,      4.00
```

With different formatting/data types. I would to construct a single combined canonical table with data from all vendors:

```
Table: canonical_vendor_sales

id,  state, sale_time,              dollars,  source,     source_id
1,  'CA',   2020-01-01 00:00:00,    4.00,     'vendor1',  1
2,  'MA',   2020-02-02 00:12:34,    0.99,     'vendor1',  2
3,  'CA',   2021-03-21 00:15:27,    0.98,     'vendor2',  1
4,  'NY',   2021-03-20 16:46:40,    4.00,     'vendor2',  2
```

Where each row is a simple transformation of the corresponding rows in the raw tables.

I would like to do this by writing a trigger for each raw table that inserts/deletes/updates the corresponding record in the canonical table whenever the raw record is changed.

How do I write this trigger? I am also open to other approaches that achieve the same goal.

Comment: Why do you want to duplicate existing data?

Comment: For example, it could make it easier and more efficient to write queries of the form `SELECT SUM(dollars) FROM canonical_vendor_sales WHERE time >= $time1 AND time < $time2`.
I can also add indexes on the canonical table.

Comment: BTW: `timestamp` and `time` are both key words. Also: why do you store one of them in an integer (?) field ?

Comment: Sorry, the column names were just for example, I'm happy to change them in practice.

`timestamp` was intended to be the unix timestamp, so e.g. `1616285727` corresponds to `2021-03-21 00:15:27` (the values in `canonical_vendor_sales` aren't correct with respect to the `timestampms` column, I just picked random times for illustration)

Comment: Answer: you don't need a trigger. And: fix your data model. And your question. [dont underestimate the readers]

Comment: I've updated the question based on the suggestions you made (no keyword columns, and `canonical_vendor_sales.sale_time` now actually matches the `vendor2_sales.unix_timestamp`.)

What do you mean by fix my data model, and that I don't need a trigger? I'm happy to take any suggestions you may have.

Comment: Your problem looks like ETL. If so, you should first ask yourself what should happen if the data cannot be converted, and what what should happen if a duplicate would occur. Also: the `id` columns look like surrogate columns; the natural key could be { [source_id, ] state, sale_time}.

Answer (score 1):

Hmm, it's odd that you have different tables for effectively the same entity and don't just have one and do the necessary conversion when importing the data. You should revise that approach. (That's what people in the comments meant by "fix your data model".)

But let's assume there is a really good reason for these multiple tables.

What you still shouldn't do is to introduce data redundancy by having another table materializing the union of theses tables. That can lead to inconsistencies and should therefore be avoided.

Try a view, something along the lines of:

```
CREATE VIEW canocial_vendor_sales
AS
SELECT location state,
       datestring::timestamp sale_time,
       cents::decimal / 100 dollars,
       'vendor1' source,
       id source_id
       FROM vendor1_sales
UNION ALL
SELECT state,
       to_timestamp(unix_timestamp) sale_time,
       dollars,
       'vendor2' source,
       id source_id
       FROM vendor2_sales;
```

(Or at least a materialized view.)

Comment: I think my main issues with this kind of approach are that
(a) you can't add indexes to a non-materialized view (b) if the view is materialized then it becomes stale over time and refreshing it can be expensive